# Bat file to automate some web development

Tags: apache-http-server, batch-file, httpd

Creating a virtualhost in Windows environment is a lot of hassle.  You have to create the site folder, edit httpd.conf, hosts and whatnow.  In order to automate some of that I decided to try and create a batch file to automate some of that.  Here what I came up with for starters:

```
@ECHO OFF

::location of vhosts
SET BASEURL=D:\web\vhosts\

:sitenameprompt
::ask for a sitename
set /p sitename="Enter Sitename: " %=%

echo Before IF
IF EXIST %BASEURL%%sitename% echo The specified site folder already exists! Choose another. 
IF EXIST %BASEURL%%sitename% goto sitenameprompt 

IF NOT EXIST %BASEURL%%sitename% echo Creating folder 
IF NOT EXIST %BASEURL%%sitename% MD %BASEURL%%sitename%

echo Adding virtualhost to httpd.conf
pause
(
echo ###%sitename%###
echo    <VirtualHost *:80>
echo        ServerAdmin admin@%sitename%
echo        DocumentRoot "%BASEURL%%sitename%"
echo        ServerName %sitename%.dev
echo        ServerAlias %sitename%.dev
echo        <Directory "%BASEURL%%sitename%">
echo            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
echo            Order allow,deny
echo            Allow from all
echo        </Directory>
echo    </VirtualHost>
) >>D:\web\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

pause
echo Restarting apache
::httpd -k restart
```

Now when running this script it gives a syntax error at the httpd.conf part.  Bear in mind I am rather new at this so its propably something obvious.  So where did I screw up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugly signs `<>|&` must be escaped in batch with a caret `^`, try this:

```
@echo off
(
echo ###%sitename%###
echo    ^<VirtualHost *:80^>
echo        ServerAdmin admin@%sitename%
echo        DocumentRoot "%BASEURL%%sitename%"
echo        ServerName %sitename%.dev
echo        ServerAlias %sitename%.dev
echo        ^<Directory "%BASEURL%%sitename%"^>
echo            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
echo            Order allow,deny
echo            Allow from all
echo        ^</Directory^>
echo    ^</VirtualHost^>
) >>D:\web\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```